# Convert tibble into a different shape

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the data found here: https://www.kaggle.com/cdc/behavioral-risk-factor-surveillance-system. In my R studio, I have named the csv file, BRFSS2015. Below is the code I am trying to execute.

```
BRFSS2015%>%
filter(!is.na(WTKG3), CHCKIDNY %in% 1:2) %>%
mutate(have_kidney_disease = CHCKIDNY == 1, 
       no_kidney_disease = CHCKIDNY == 2,
       weight = WTKG3) %>%
group_by(have_kidney_disease, no_kidney_disease) %>%
summarize(mean_weight = mean(weight),
          sd_weight = sd(weight), 
          .groups = "drop")%>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)
```

This is giving me output that is a 2x4 tibble. The columns are `have_kidney_disease`, `no_kidney disease`, `mean_weight`, and `sd_weight`. I want to convert this into a 4x4 format, where `have_kidney_disease` and `no_kidney_disease` are rows. How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you first creating 2 different columns for kidney disease? If you use an `if_else` or a `case_when` statement you have the values in 1 column and can use that one in the group by and you will have no need to convert the tibble in a long format.

Comment: Because you have just taught me something new.  I am brand new to R. Can you please demonstrate what you are talking about, and then I will have learned a lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will get you there. If you want to rename columns don't do it inside a mutate but use `rename(weight = WTKG3)` as a statement after you use `select` or `filter`. But as you don't actually use this column except as a replacement in the `summarize` function, there is no need to do this.

I used a `case_when` statement so you can see how it that works. For just 2 values it is simpler to use an `if_else`. Below I gave 2 different solutions, the first as you had your code, the second without filtering on CHCKIDNY to show you how the `case_when` deals with other values.

```
BRFSS2015%>%
  filter(!is.na(WTKG3), CHCKIDNY %in% 1:2) %>%
  mutate(kidney_disease = case_when(CHCKIDNY == 1 ~ "yes",
                                    CHCKIDNY == 2 ~ "no")) %>% 
  group_by(kidney_disease) %>% 
  summarize(mean_weight = mean(WTKG3),
            sd_weight = sd(WTKG3))



# A tibble: 2 × 3
  kidney_disease mean_weight sd_weight
  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>
1 no                   8081.     2152.
2 yes                  8392.     2363.
```

No filter on CHCKIDNY

```
BRFSS2015%>%
  filter(!is.na(WTKG3)) %>%
  mutate(kidney_disease = case_when(CHCKIDNY == 1 ~ "yes",
                                    CHCKIDNY == 2 ~ "no",
                                    TRUE ~ "unknown")) %>% 
  group_by(kidney_disease) %>% 
  summarize(mean_weight = mean(WTKG3),
            sd_weight = sd(WTKG3))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  kidney_disease mean_weight sd_weight
  <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>
1 no                   8081.     2152.
2 unknown              8263.     2252.
3 yes                  8392.     2363.
```

Comment: Thanks that's awesome! I definitely prefer case_when() to my method. Technically I still want a 2x2, with kidney disease yes/no=row labels, do I install reshape() package for that?  Or is this not important?

Comment: @jakdar, If you really want to you can use the function `tibble::column_to_rownames("kidney_disease")` after the summarize to get get the yes/no as row names.